# Cannot declare global variables with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am in the process of getting rid of most global variables in my program, but some will always be useful.

I have looked up answers to this several times and gave up finding an answer on my own - the supposed way to declare a global var with TS is like so:

```
declare var x: string;
```

which would translate to - `global.x = 'foo';`

but this declaration is not getting rid of the compilations errors or IDE warnings in Webstorm.

What is the best way to declare global vars in my program? I assume the best way to do it would involve a `.d.ts` file.

Here is the type of warning I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it:

in my file in my project called `suman.d.ts`, I have:

```
import Global = NodeJS.Global;

interface SumanGlobal extends Global {
  _writeTestError: Function,
  sumanRuntimeErrors: Array<Error | string>,
  sumanOpts: Object,
  sumanUncaughtExceptionTriggered: boolean
}

declare var global: SumanGlobal;
```

seems to work for the moment